# Does invisibility end for opportunity attack for Assassin's "Vanish" or "Slayer's Escape" power?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, invisibility, assassin

In DND 4e, does the invisibility effect of an Assassin's "Vanish" or "Slayer's Escape" power end if the assassin makes an opportunity attack before the start of their turn?

Most other powers I've seen with an invisibility effect end when the player makes an attack but these two powers don't contain that text. Does this rule not apply to these two powers?

The keyword shadow and teleportation make me wonder if maybe they are invisible because they are actually teleporting through the shadowfell.

If that's the case, could they even make an opportunity attack?

The other invisibility powers I have seen are mostly illusion-based powers.

Answer (score 3):

#### Invisiblity from these powers does *not* end when you make an opportunity attack.

From Heroes of Shadow, p25:

> **Vanish**
>   ...
>   *Effect:* You become invisible until the start of your next turn, and you teleport up to your speed.

Nothing in the power says you become visible if you attack.

From the Rules Compendium, p221:

> **Invisibility**
>   ...
>   * It can't be seen by normal forms of vision.
>   * It has total concealment against any enemy that can't see it.
>   * It has combat advantage against any enemy that can't see it (but it still has to be able to see the enemy).
>   * It doesn't provoke opportunity attacks from enemies that can't see it.

Nothing in the rules for invisibility says it ends when you attack.

Since invisibility in general doesn't automatically end when you attack, and the power doesn't say that it ends when you attack, it does not end when you attack.

---

#### Other Concerns

Not having these powers end on an attack is fairly reasonable, since they're reaction powers whose benefit ends at the start of your next turn; you can't use them to become invisible to make normal attacks on your turn. Opportunity attacks and granted attacks (from warlords, etc.) are the *only* attacks you'll be able to make while invisible thanks to these powers, and those just aren't strong enough to be a real balance issue. Furthermore, there's no way to *guarantee* that you'll be able to make an opportunity attack during the invisibility period.

The *Shadow* keyword these powers have is a power source keyword. Just like rangers, rogues, warlords, and fighters have the *Martial* keyword on all their powers because they are martial classes, and sorcerers, warlocks, wizards, and swordmages have the *Arcane* keyword on all their powers because they are arcane classes, the assassin has the *Shadow* keyword on its powers because it is a shadow class. In fact, it is the **only** shadow class; WotC originally intended to add ki & shadow to the list of power sources, but they couldn't come up with enough classes to flesh them out. Monks were made psychic instead of ki, and assassins got left as the only class of the wildly under-supported shadow power source.

The *Teleportation* keyword is present because these powers also allow you to teleport. This does not indicate that their invisibility is teleportation-based. There are powers that actually send combatants to other planes for brief periods of time, and they universally remove the target from play for their duration, rather than making them invisible. Invisibility means "present but not visible", as opposed to "temporarily not present".

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Very informative! Makes total sense.

Comment: @qradley Happy to help! If this solved your problem, you can mark it as the solution to your problem by clicking on the checkmark just below the up & down vote buttons at the top left of the answer.